# Giving discord members with a certain status a role

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Let me explain, So I want to give everyone on my discord server with the status discord.gg/chilling a role!

So far I came up with this logic

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=1.0)
async def give_role():
    guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, name="TOG")
    role = discord.utils.get(client.guilds[0].roles, name="I Am Sexier")
    [member.add_roles(role) for member in guild.members if 'discord.gg/chilling' in member.activities[0].name]

give_role.start()
```

Now the problem is, I want it to keep iterating over and over again and I couldn't think of an idea to do that!
Ik this website is filled with geniuses, so anyone got ideas?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: member.status.name does not return what we call status in discord so like setting a custom status. Instead it returns the statuses: `dnd (Do not disturd), online, offline and idle`

Comment: @Remi_Zacharias not really it actually does return the status, im running it in my user status command rn

Comment: That's wierd as by me when I did `status = member.status.name` and then printed the status, it just returned those dnd, online offline etc

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/) for that. Tasks are basicly repeats the code that you wrote periodically. Also you can't add role with the role's name. You should use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=1.0)
async def give_role():
    guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, name="Your guild's name")
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Role's name")
    [member.add_roles(role) for member in guild.members if 'discord.gg/chilling' in member.activities[0].name]
```

Then you can start your loop with `give_role.start()`.

**EDIT**

For getting the `CustomStatus` of the member, you can use `member.activities[0].name`.

Comment: I'm gonna try this!

Comment: How do I fix tasks not defined?

Comment: I fixed tasks not defined but uhhh, it doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: Is there any error? This task will run every minute. Can you show your code?

Comment: You must use `give_role.start()` on the `on_ready()` function. also import it as follows `from discord.ext import tasks`

Comment: @Nurqm can you check now? i just changed member.status.name to member.activity

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to get the activity name that you want.

Comment: I found a way to get the status. Check the edit of the answer.

Comment: @Nurqm seems that you're a genius and im dumb i didnt even call the function lmao
but im getting nonetype has no attribute roles, how could i fix?

Comment: Did you replace the `Your guild's name` place with your actual guild's name and `Role's name` with an actual role name?

Comment: is your bot on more than one guild?

Comment: Exactly 1 @Nurqm

Comment: So can you replace `role = discord.utils.get(client.guilds[0].roles, name="Role's name")` with `role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Role's name")`?

Comment: one sec lemme do it real quick

Comment: @Nurqm list index out of range

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea to fix the problem.